# Accessing Hadoop Cloud services from Windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, mapreduce, cloud

I am new to hadoop. I am using [already hadoop configured](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html) VM provided by yahoo, since i am not allowed to install Linux OS in my machine. 
I need to avail cloud services and have to work on hadoop related projects.

[Microsoft Insight](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/?WT.mc_id=AzureBG_US_Display_Q3_GrSP_NETV1C) was providing those services few days back. But now it has become a paid one.Moreover i am developing MapReduce program in Java.

When i search like "Hadoop & Cloud" in google most of the times i get[CLoudera's cloud offering](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/why-cloudera/hadoop-and-big-data.html).

But to access it they have asked to [install something called "Whirr"](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Whirr+Installation), since i am working in windows based platform only i couldn't work it out.

I also checked [Joynet](http://joyent.com/products/joyent-cloud/features/hadoop). But it is also a paid one.

I thought the cloud access would be like connecting the cloud with an IP from MSTSC.
But it is not that way.
I need to play around hadoop over cloud from windows.
How can i do that?.Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstanding about cloud in general and then Hadoop in cloud. In Cloud scenario the application or infrastructure both are remotely located at cloud vendor location and use access/manage/configure them remotely as the need arise.

So if you want to access Hadoop in cloud, the Hadoop cluster must be located in cloud first and then you can access it. You would need to shell out few dollars to have Hadoop on cloud. You can use [HDInsight (Hadoop on Windows Azure)](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/)  or [Amazon EMR](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) cloud based Hadoop services. With these cloud services you will have Hadoop cluster already built and ready for you to push the data and apply your job.